# Converting string obtained from element's data attribute to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get an error with the following code. I know `$.parseJSON()` is sensitive to single/double quotes. I cannot think of a solution to this problem. Can you please help !

```
<div data-x='{"a":"1","b":"2"}'></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var data =$.parseJSON($("div").data("x"))
    alert(data.a)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r2Lnfbpm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `data()` does type conversion, so when the data attribute is valid JSON, it's already parsed into an object, and passing an object to `$.parseJSON` produces an error, as it expects a string of JSON.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $("div").data("x");
    console.log(data.a);
});
```

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> **Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value**
>   *(this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)*.
>   A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's
>   representation.
>
> For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as
>   numbers *(numeric value 100)* but converting them would alter their
>   representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is
>   converted to the number 100.
>
> **When the data attribute is an object** *(starts with '{') or array
>   (starts with '[')* **then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string**;
>   it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If
>   the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a
>   string.
>
> To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to
>   convert it, use the `attr()` method.